# Are badges specific to the site?

Tags: discussion

Basically, are the badges that a user can be awarded on StackOverflow the same as the badges that can be awarded on any of the StackExchange sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not always. For example, [this badge](https://stackapps.com/badges/60/api-evangelist) comes with 4000 rep bonus attached to it :) Area 51 has some specific badges too.

But usually, there's little reason for site-specific badges.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.  Of course, there are two *kinds* of badges: the "regular" badges (for specific "feats"), and the tag-badges.  Those are of course (somewhat, there's overlap) site-specific.

In case you don't know what a tag-badge is: you get them for upvotes for answers on questions of that tag.  To get the "discussion" bronze tag badge, you need 100 upvotes for answers given to questions tagged "discussion".